# Can't see headers after they're sent. (Sendgrid)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sendgrid

I'm having a trouble about the error on my web application though it succesfully send and confirm an email i don't want a single error to be seen on the console . I just want to ask something if it is about the double callback that i did, here is my code:

```
User.findOne({authToken: req.query.token}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(user);

        user.IsAuthenticated = true;
        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully updated user');
                console.log(user);
                //resend email
                sendgrid.send({
                    to:     user.email,
                    from:   'pektospioneers.com',
                    subject:'Email COnfirmed!',
                    html:   'Thank you'
                }, function(err, json){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                });
                res.send(user);
            }
        });
    }
});
    req.flash("success_msg",'Email has been confirmed!');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
});
```

Now the error was

> Can't see headers after they're sent.

Is this because of my

```
function(err,user){
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
  }
 else{
  console.log(user);
  }
}
```

as you can see there's a lot of callbacks that i did . Was it related to the error? Please someone explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
User.findOne({authToken: req.query.token}, function(err, user){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return res.send(err);
} else {
    console.log(user);
    user.IsAuthenticated = true;
    user.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully updated user');
            console.log(user);
            //resend email
            sendgrid.send({
                to:     user.email,
                from:   'pektospioneers.com',
                subject:'Email COnfirmed!',
                html:   'Thank you'
            }, function(err, json){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.send(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(json);
                    req.flash("success_msg",'Email has been confirmed!');
                    res.redirect('/users/login');
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findOne({authToken: req.query.token}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        console.log(user);
        user.IsAuthenticated = true;
        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully updated user');
                console.log(user);

                sendgrid.send({
                    to:     user.email,
                    from:   'pektospioneers.com',
                    subject:'Email COnfirmed!',
                    html:   'Thank you'
                }, function(err, json){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
    req.flash("success_msg",'Email has been confirmed!');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
```